# Losing Drivers and Functionality on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, 13.10, bug-reporting

I have a machine that runs ubuntu 13.10. It has been slowly but surely losing system functionality for a couple of months. Application center stopped working a couple of months ago because X Drawable disappeared. Now the clock functionality is gone and it can no longer play sound at all. Is this a problem with my install? I am using an ASUS X201EP That I bought from CDW 9 months ago. Intel 847 processor and 3.7 gb ram... Not sure if that's relevant

Here's the output `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0106] (rev 09)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:108d]
Kernel driver in use: i915
```

When I tried downloading the linux graphics installer and running `sudo dpkg -i [filename]` I got this output

```
(Reading database ... 254111 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking intel-linux-graphics-installer (from intel-linux-graphics-                       installer_1.0.3_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of intel-linux-graphics-installer:
intel-linux-graphics-installer depends on libpackagekit-glib2-16 (>= 0.8.10);         however:
Package libpackagekit-glib2-16 is not installed.
 intel-linux-graphics-installer depends on ttf-ancient-fonts; however:
 Package ttf-ancient-fonts is not installed.

dpkg: error processing intel-linux-graphics-installer (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for mime-support ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
intel-linux-graphics-installer
```

I tried modifying the grub as the tutorial JohnnyD. Recommended and now I can no longer load gnome and I get 'could not open x display' and 'could not find display 0'... I would post full output but I am posting from my phone cause I can't open chromium

Comment: Is it up-to-date? any property driver installed?

Comment: Yeah I ran 'sudo apt-get update' I am pretty clueless... What is a property driver?

Comment: Proprietary driver, from `Additional Drivers`.

Comment: @landroni I haven't consciously installed any. How would I check to be sure

Comment: Access `Additional Drivers` from the menus, or execute `jockey-gtk` in a terminal.

Comment: @landroni Updater says there are none available

Comment: can you add the output to your question please: `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA` and we'll see where we can go from there

Comment: there are problems with your driver i915 stability so I combined a solution from searches I'll provide it in answer and you'll do the workout and see if it help you.

Comment: take a look at this [thread](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/showthread.php?t=48904) also may wanna try to add this ppa `apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers) and run update and upgrade option.

Comment: May be your hard disk is failing?

Comment: @JohnnyD. I tried the thread you mentioned but now it boots to terminal after step 2 and i am stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes to this in the future. I had to revert the operating system to factory install after backing up all of my files. Press `esc` on startup and and press restore to factory settings.

This helps: http://liliputing.com/2011/07/how-to-install-nearly-any-linux-distro-using-a-usb-flash-drive-and-unetbootin.html

Answer (score -1):

Install linux drivers from intel, from [here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/). Select ubuntu 13.10 and 32 bit or 64 bit , depending on your system. you can check which architecture(32/64 bit) is in system settings -> Details, here: [image]

Comment: This did not work had dependency problems

Comment: That's impossible. I installed it succesfully on 13.10 64 bit. It's the first thing anyone should install on ubuntu.