# How do I reset/fix the Winetricks GUI?

Tags: wine, gui, winetricks

One day I was messing around in wine to try to install a few Windows components.  For some reason, Winetricks has now completely shrunken the area of the window where I can select what I want to do and I can't do anything in it now.  I know it's possible to do Winetricks stuff through command line, but I'd prefer a GUI when available. Here's a screenshot of what I mean.[image: Clickable area shrunken to right underneath headers]

The choices used to have a bit of space, but now it's just shrunken to the point where nothing is choose-able, because now it's just a white line. I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling Winetricks, but no dice...

Comment: Have you tried removing it using `apt-get purge`?

Answer (score 0):

if you want graphical GUI use `Synaptic Package Manager` if you don't have it install it using terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

open Synaptic clicking on Ubuntu Dash Logo or hit `super key` and type `synaptic` open and search for your `Winetricks` version installed click on a `mark` opposite to package name and choose `complete removal` and at the top of window press `apply` then install it again.

Comment: What I meant by graphical was I prefered having an interface when dealing with wine configuration, I should've been a bit more clear.  By marking for complete removal, wouldn't it remove Wine as well, or would it only remove Winetricks and it's files?

Comment: in pop up window it will tell you what is going to be deleted

Comment: Well, I tried it through both sudo apt-get purge winetricks and the way you mentioned via synaptic, all that happened is that i can just barely see one option at a time.  So we're getting there.  Note I am currently using the XFCE DE, but this happened while I still had the Unity DE (which I removed, too laggy and I don't use it anymore).

Comment: can you give me the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA` is that only happens to Wine? And what happens when you run `sudo apt-get remove --purge winetricks` ?

Comment: Well, I did what you said and got the output. I also added some additional info, here's the info: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/EDDCmeGK)

Comment: well there are some issues may be with your i915 driver and not the Winetricks take a look at this [thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425723/losing-drivers-and-functionality-on-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment556173_425723)